# Divide a list into columns ordered vertically using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to break-down a long list of items into columns using xslt 1.0 that should be ordered vertically. I have seen solutions on how to do this with horizontal ordering but cannot figure out how to this vertically.

Here is sample input:

```
<list>
 <item>1</item>
 <item>2</item>
 <item>3</item>
 <item>4</item>
 <item>5</item>
 <item>6</item>
 <item>7</item>
 <item>8</item>
 <item>9</item>
 <item>10</item>
 <item>11</item>
 <item>12</item>
 <item>13</item>
 <item>14</item>
</list>
```

Here is the desired output (3 columns):

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>6</td>
 <td>11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>2</td>
 <td>7</td>
 <td>12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>3</td>
 <td>8</td>
 <td>13</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>4</td>
 <td>9</td>
 <td>14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>5</td>
 <td>10</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The example is ambiguous. Please show the expected result when there are 14 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work for you. It divides the items into (any) given number of columns and populates these columns using the "down first" method.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="columns" select="3" />

<xsl:template match="/list">
    <xsl:variable name="rows" select="ceiling(count(item) div $columns)" />
    <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="item[position() &lt;= $rows]">
            <xsl:variable name="row" select="position() mod $rows" />
            <tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="../item[position() mod $rows = $row]"/>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following input example:

**XML**

```
<list>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>11</item>
    <item>12</item>
    <item>13</item>
    <item>14</item>
</list>
```

the result will be:

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>11</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>12</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>13</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>14</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>10</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

rendered as:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I need. You guessed the expected behaviour before I could clarify the example ;) I didn't think about the mod trick